# Airbyte - Spark SQL query keeps failing (Updates are in conflict for these columns: data_user_id)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, airbyte

I have coded an airbyte custom destination using python. I have implemented an incremental sync dedup operation using this query,

```
MERGE INTO {self.schema_name}.{table_name} AS target
USING {self.schema_name}.{table_name}_temp AS source
ON target.data_{primary_keys[0][0]}=source.data_{primary_keys[0][0]}
WHEN MATCHED THEN
        {query_placeholder_refined}
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT *
```

here the `query_placeholder_refined` variable is replaced with an `UPDATE SET` query statement where all the columns of the target table are updated respectively, take for instance a simplified version of the query could be,

```
MERGE INTO integration.issues as target
USING integration.issues_temp as source
ON target.data_id=source.data_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET target.data_issue_url=source.data_issue_url, target.data_user_id=source.data_user_id 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT *
```

the query runs perfectly for a few streams but for other streams it gives this error,
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Updates are in conflict for these columns: data_user_id`

Comment: Do you have foreign keys between the table that you're trying to update and other tables in the database specifically a foreign key on the `data_user_id`

Comment: Yes, that is actually the case, so, every stream comes with its own primary key, in most of the streams the PK is `data_id` but in a very few streams the PK is `data_user_id` and that is exactly where it gives me the aforementioned error. But if I remove this specific column from the query (basically hard code the query) then this error goes away, any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the query is perfect and works like a charm the problem was that I wasn't giving the correct columns in the `UPDATE SET` line of the query which is why SQL was throwing the aforementioned error, the error basically translates to, it was unable to find the given column name in the table.

#### Solution 1

Change the column names with `UPDATE SET *`

#### Solution 2

Giving the correct column names to the query.